# Regular Expression for an infinite string

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to figure out whether u could give a regular expression for the set of substrings of an infinite string for example if the infinite string was 123123123123123123...

would there be a regular expression that describes this,
for example i've tried (123)*|(231)*|(312)*
but that won't work as i need to account for 12 being in the string and 23

Comment: You want to match all substrings of that infinite string?

Comment: There must be more conditions, otherwise its just `(?=(\d{3}))`

Comment: `(123)+` - http://regexr.com/3c9i3

Answer (score 1):

Define the 'infinite' string as the concatenation of an infinite number of copies of the same base string `<base>` ( `123` in your example ). Start with the observation that any substring has the following parts occurring in the given order:

1. A suffix of `<base>` or the empty string
2. 0 or more repetitions of `<base>`
3. A prefix of `<base>` or the empty string

In regex parlance that translates into

1. An optional alternation of all `<base>` suffixes
2. The Kleene operator applied to `<base>`
3. An optional alternation of all `<base>` prefixes

Specifically:

```
(23|3)?(123)*(1|12)?
```

This solution expressly allows for the empty substring. In order to rule out that case, either the prefix or the suffix or the middle part must not be empty. This can be achieved by alternations of different variations of the complete pattern.

```
123|((23|3)(123)*(1|12)?)|((23|3)?(123)*(1|12))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think [this is the closest you're going to get with](http://bit.ly/1kTCxQg) validating "patterns."  Otherwise, if you need more variability, you're going to need (at least) the aid of middle-layer processing with your choice of programming language.

```
^(?<detectPattern>
  123
  |132
  |213
  |231
  |312
  |321
)\k<detectPattern>*$
```

The pattern is written with using the reference at the end to visually explain how it's matching at the beginning.  Otherwise, you could just as easily remove `\k<detectPattern>`, but maintain the `*`.

Comment: Your pattern seems flawed. First, it will not match against infinite strings because of the anchors. Second, dropping the anchors, it will only identify strings of length `3 * n; n=1, 2,...`. Even worse, it does not match sub*strings* but sub*sequences* ( e.g. `132` occurs nowhere in the OP's example string as a substring). Finally, it does not identify *all*  subsequences ( but then, if that had been the OP's demand, the solution would simply be `[123]+`).

Comment: @collaspar His example was on one line. Adding `132` was just another combination of the numbers that were given to illustrate a way of accomplishing the end result.

Comment: @collaspar Also, infinite should be a relative term being considered for how a regular expression would be applied. There needs to be some form of finite end for the regular expression to ever be able to succeed to validate said pattern. Otherwise, anything you throw at it will eventually fail due to too much processing/cycles. "I think" wasn't asserting that my solution was the 100% mark. It was what I felt was the closest (practical) approach for attaining some form of detection at the beginning and validating for the rest of the string.

Comment: The major point about regexen is the ability to concisely represent (a certain class of) infinite strings. This is a useful abstraction which is not offset by the finiteness of physical resources (one will discuss asymptotic complexity of algorithms though in the physical world everything boils down to `O(1)`), think of continuous stream processing. Moreover (as far as I understand), the OP asked  for a regex to describe the set of possible substrings, which is different from a regex to detect the start of an infinite string's prefix and which has different use cases.

Comment: I'm conceding on this, considering it took me less time to write the aforementioned regex than it has justifying my approach.